# is there something similar to f command in vim for multiple chars?

Tags: vim

Beginning to use vim as a macro, is there an `f` command but instead of catching single char i want to catch multiple chars? While I know I can use the `/` I didn't see that I could repeat it with the `;` to take me to the next target only with `f`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get to the next target with `n` and to the previous one with `N` when using `/`.

Answer (score 4):

Put your cursor on the word and pres:

- `gd` - goto first one
- `#` - goto previous
- `*` - goto next

and then `n` or `N` to repeat.

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is that `/` is interactive (meaning: you have to type something) and you want to use that in a fixed value macro, then you can still do it.

For example if you do:

`:map g /something^M`

then you hit `g`, it will look for the string `something`.

Keep in mind that `^M` is the combination of keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

As a side note, the same goes when you want to enter some text and go back to normal mode:

`:map g 0i--^[j`

If you hit `g` it will insert `--` at the beginning of the line and move down one line.

Here `^[` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: Simpler, and less brittle: `nnoremap g /something<CR>`